# No User Identity Being Created From JWT Token

Tags: authentication, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .Net Core 2 Web API project that is using JwtBearer Authentication.  However, while this works in regards to Authenticating my user and respecting the `[Authorize]` attribute on my controller, the User Identity and Claims are never populated.  Is there something more I have to do to create ensure that a ClaimsIdentity is created for my authenticated user?

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ...
   services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
      .AddJwtBearer(options => 
      {
          options.Authority = "https://myTenant.auth0.com";
          options.Audience = "https://localhost:5001/api/v1";
          options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

          options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
          {
             ValidateIssuer = true,
             ValidateAudience = true,
             ValidateLifetime = true,
             ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
             ValidIssuer = "myTenant.auth0.com",
             ValidAudience = "https://localhost:5001/api/v1"
          };
     });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, SystemModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   ...
   app.UseHttpsRedirection();
   app.UseAuthentication();
}
```

My token looks like this on jwt.ms:

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
.{
  "profileData": {
     "given_name": "Rodd",
     "family_name": "Harris"
  },
  "iss": "https://myTenant.auth0.com/",
  "sub": "auth0|37b5f5c54fdac",
  "aud": [
     "https://localhost:5050/api/v1/",
     "https://myTenant.auth0.com/userinfo"
  ],
  "iat": 1532628090,
  "exp": 1532629290,
  "azp": "2RdsNtKpUgh_wgB3NI6gxd-OAl",
  "scope": "openid profile email app.client.read"
}.[Signature]
```

In my controller, I have something like this:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
[Authorize]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("clients")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ClientsList()
    {
       //Debugger gets here -- user is authenticated           
       var user = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name; //Always null
       var count = HttpContext.User.Claims.Count(); //Always 0
       var allowed = HttpContext.User.IsAuthenticated;  //Always true
       var type = HttpContext.User.AuthenticationType; //AuthenticationTypes.Federated
       ...
    }
```

What keeps the user's name and claims from being created?

**Update**

So I just realized I AM actually getting the claims mapped into `HttpContext.User.Identity.Claims`.  Also realized that my token doesn't have a name value to automagically map to the Identity.  So, I guess my real question is, how do I override the custom mapping and do my own mapping of the token into an Identity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the information [here](http://benfoster.io/blog/customising-claims-transformation-in-aspnet-core-identity) and [here](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/overriding-name-claimtype-aspnetcore-oidc/), I was able to figure out what was going on.

First, .Net apparently tries to automap from the token claims by looking for the claim identified by the key: `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name`.  Of course, I didn't have this in my token -- so no default name mapping.

In fact, I realized I didn't have ANY name being passed in my token -- so I had to set up a Rule on Auth0 to include something to use as a name.  (I did have a name in app_metadata, but I needed to flatten that out into separate values).

Once that was done, I simply needed to tell .Net to use a different key to find the name claim in the list of token claims.  I did this in Startup.cs like so:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddJwtBearer(options => 
   {
      options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
      {
          ...
          //There is no magic to this string -- it is whatever claim key is being
          //issued by the Auth Provider
          NameClaimType = "https://myshcemadefinedkey/preferred_username" 
      }
    }
```

With that in place, .Net began populating the User.Identity.Name value with the value associated with the token claim that had the corresponding key value.

Comment: I used the following claim type for AWS Cognito in order to get the "sub" identifier: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier

Comment: I have been pulling my hair out for two days until I found this solution. Thank you!! Can anyone explain why this works? Might this be a bug or is it caused due to fixing a bug in earlier implementation of the JWT handling?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe correct your Configure to get this :

```
app.UseIdentity();
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions()
{
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,


            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidIssuer = _config["Tokens:Issuer"],
                ValidAudience = _config["Tokens:Audience"],
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Tokens:Key"])),
                ValidateLifetime = true
            }
        });
```

And be carefull to put this before your UseMvc();

Comment: So, when I try this, VS tells me that `app.UseIdentity()` is obsolete and to use `app.UseAuthentication()` instead -- which is what I'm already doing.

Comment: The most important is UseJwtBearerAuthentication

Comment: You must be using an older version of .net core.  `app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication` is also obsolete.